# Adding elements of a specific column of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Well. I am having an issue with the addition of elements in one column. the array is user defined. well instead of adding first column my code is adding third row. Well my code is working with predefined array but not with user defined array. like below!

```
int r, c, array[r][c], sum = 0;
cout<<"Enter number of Rows ";
cin>>r;
cout<<"Enter number of columns ";
cin>>c;
for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
    {
        cout<<i<<j<<")";
        cin>>array[i][j];
    }
}
for(int l=0; l<r; l++)
{
    for(int k=0; k<c; k++)
    {
            if(l==0)
            {
                sum = sum + array[l][k];
            }
    }
}
cout<<"Sum for first colomn is "<<sum;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewrop.jpg)

Comment: Why dont you directly loop over the first column, you dont need two loops

Comment: By the way first column is when k==0

Comment: Variable sized arrays is not valid C++

Answer (score 1):

You declare the array before `r` and `c` are initialized:

```
int r, c, array[r][c], sum = 0;
```

Asking the user for the values of `r` and `c` afterwards wont help. Even if you first ask for the size and then declare the array, `array[r][c]` is a variable length array (VLA) which is not standard C++.

`std::vector` is for dynamically sized arrays:

```
int r,c;
std::cin >> r >> c;
std::vector< std::vector<int>> array(r, std::vector<int>(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake is you are using

```
int r, c, array[r][c], sum = 0;
```

this line for the initialization of your 2D array. But the value in `r` and `c` is garbage. So, you 2D array will not get created according to your desire.It will assign your input values to the random addresses. You should create you 2D array dynamically(if you want to use user specific array size) after getting the input from user.

For this purpose, you need to be familiar with `new` keyword which dynamically create the array of user defined type.

The second mistake is you are applying if condition on the rows here `if(l==0)` because `l` is representing rows there, you should replace it with `k`  which is representing column here to get the sum of the column.
Here is the correct version of your code

```
int r, c, sum = 0;
int **array;
cout<<"Enter number of Rows ";
cin>>r;
cout<<"Enter number of columns ";
cin>>c;
array = new int*[r];
for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    array[i]=new int[c];
}
for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
    {
        cout<<i<<j<<")";
        cin>>array[i][j];
    }
}
for(int l=0; l<r; l++)
{
    for(int k=0; k<c; k++)
    {
            if(k==0)

            {
                sum = sum + array[l][k];
            }
    }
}
cout<<"Sum for first colomn is "<<sum;
```

**Note:** DONT FORGET TO FREE THE DYNAMICALLY ASSIGNED MEMORY.

You can also use `vector` from the `stl` library. Which is very handy to use for dynamic user defined arrays once you familiar with it.

Comment: Well, K replaced L with l because i thought that it would be easy to to use it in the outer loop!

Comment: The outer loop is for the row, so if you use 'l' the will sim the row,
the inner loop is for column so you need ti use 'k' to sum up the column. 
vote up if you need it helpful, Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

3 error in this code:

- first of all, you initialize array with dimension r and c variable `before you have initilize them`. (you can't use pre-allocated dimension array if use the input of the operator, but can use or a std::vector or a dinamic allocation on an double pointer variable, another solution can be oversize the array at the startup and then use only the rows and columns you need)
- the second one you have to use `k==0` for first column and not `l==0`.
- the third one now is a question of performance, why you use a nested for loop if the index of the column is fixed? *You can  directly access the variable without **"if"** and **"for"***

Comment: Appreciated <3.